# dynamically creat variable by predefined list

Tags: python, list, variables, numpy, matplotlib

Here is my idea, and I met some problem that I can't cope with.

#### *My attempt*

Creat cmap_1, cmap_2, cmap_3, ....by pre-defined color_list.

#### *My code*

```
color_list = ['#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99',\
              '#e31a1c','#fdbf6f','#ff7f00','#cab2d6','#6a3d9a','#ffff99']    

## generate the suffix (1,2,3,4...)
letter = np.arange(1,len(site_s)+1,1)    
## Loop to generate cmap_i = colors.ListedColormap(["w",color_list[i]]) 
for i in range(0,len(letter),1):
    eval("cmap_%s" % (letter[i])) = colors.ListedColormap(["w",color_list[i]])
```

But it seems that eval(xxx) doesn't work. I think `eval` function only can be used when cmap_1,...cmap_n are already exist.

So, here is my question in one word

> How to creat a new variable **cmap_i**?

*Add 1*

1. After creating these variable, I will plot 2-d pcolormesh with 11 2-d np-array using `cmap_i` in one figure.

For example

- *value* is a 3-d numpy array in the shape of (11,50,50). '11' is the amount of the 2-d array.
- *value* only has two number 0 & 1. So, I want to creat different two colormap correspoding to each 2-d numpy array. And then, "1" for each 2-d array has a different color. That's what I'm going to do

*Code*:

```
for i in range(0,value.shape[0],1):
    plt.pcolormesh(value[i,:,:],cmap = cmap_i) ##  cmap = cmap_i was the fake code.
```

2. I have read this question("How do I do variable variables in Python?"), and I'm still confused.

*Add 2*
Here is what I do for now

```
color_list =['#a6cee3','#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#33a02c','#fb9a99',\
             '#e31a1c','#fdbf6f','#ff7f00','#cab2d6','#6a3d9a','#ffff99']
cmap1 =cmap2=cmap3=cmap4=cmap5=cmap6=cmap7=\
cmap8=cmap9=cmap10=cmap11 = plt.cm.jet
CMAP = [cmap1 , cmap2, cmap3, cmap4, cmap5, cmap6, cmap7, 
        cmap8, cmap9, cmap10, cmap11 ]
for i in range(0,len(color_list),1):
    CMAP[i]= colors.ListedColormap([color_list[i]])
```

Comment: Why create a bunch of named variables, rather than sticking them in a list?

Comment: Is that can be execute  automatically?

Comment: The real question is, assuming you can create these variables, what kind of code are you going to write to use them? How will you write code that can access a variable number of variables?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think he's trying to create methods, not variables

Comment: @IliyanBobev `ListedColormap` would be a class, based on the naming, but you can put anything in a list/dict so it doesn't really matter what the value would be - the point is that dynamic naming is unnecessary.

Comment: @HanZhengzu lookup `setattr ` for programmatically creating methods